# Comparing local csvs to write updates, list(set()) issue

Tags: list, csv, set, comparison

I have a funny problem. I can get the unique rows in the two comparison csv files by using:

```
update = list(set(compareNew) - set(compareOld))
```

However, when I include this line in my function I get *TypeError:'list' object is not callable.*

I need to do this for a few hundred csv's so I am calling the above line in a loop. Does that change anything for the function?

Using python 3.4

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by subtracting the two sets, then appending the difference to a list in a subloop.

Makes it a two-step process, but it appears to work